# python slack API missing scope error despite appropriate scope for the bot token

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I am trying to create a Slack API + Python web hook. I have setup the app and the bot tokens with the proper scope needed to create DM's with users and post messages. I am trying a sample script that will open channel.

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
from slack_sdk import WebClient

slack_token = "xoxb-<random_value>"
client = WebClient(token=slack_token)

api_response = client.conversations_open(channel="user1")
```

I get an error response from the API:

```
slack_sdk.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://www.slack.com/api/conversations.open)
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'missing_scope', 'needed': 'channels:write,groups:write,mpim:write,im:write', 'provided': 'incoming-webhook'}
```

[image: Bot scopes added]

Can someone please help ? For some reason, it identifies only the incoming-webhook. First time doing this. Any help appreciated